# Dynamic Form Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

I use Symfony 3

I wanted to know if it was possible to make dynamic forms?

Explanation: 
Imagine that I have a first , how to make that in the second select, I have different data according to the choice in the select 1?

If my first select is "Girl", I want in my second select:  "Katie". And if in the first select  I have "Boy", I want in the second select: "Brice".

I do not see how to do without reloading the page ..

Thanks you advance ..

Comment: You have to do this manually using javascript in client side & form events on server side.

Comment: Take a look at this, there is everywhere you need in server side and on client side https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to have to refresh the page you have two options:

- Either you load everything initially and save it in a [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) and then change (for example) the options of a select.
- Another way (perhaps more used) is that with ajax (or similar) ask for the data that will be loaded in the next select after choosing in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

In any case you have to control the options of the second select through Javascript. A good choice for such a plugin if you are using jQuery would be kartik's [dependent-dropdown](https://github.com/kartik-v/dependent-dropdown).